# Book about an alien insectoid civilization and their journey from pre-space-travel to the stars?

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to remember the author and title of a book I read 30 years ago or so, about a race of insectoid aliens and their journey from pre-space-age, to being able to travel between the stars. Kind of a Foundation-scale scope, but just a single book. The perspective jumps by generations throughout the history of this civilization.

I thought it was Brin, or Saberhagen, or Pohl, but I've not been able to find the book listed in any of their bibliographies.

Ring any bells?

Comment: Reminds me of [A Deepness in the Sky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Deepness_in_the_Sky), but that's only 16 years old.

Comment: Yeah, loved that book, too, but definitely wasn't that.

Comment: They are not really insectoids, but [Dragon's Egg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon's_Egg) by Robert L. Forward deals with similar themes across one volume.

Comment: Dragon's Egg was awesome, but not the one I'm thinking of. I'm pretty sure the one I'm looking for had no humans in it. Just that one alien race.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Someone helped me off-list: the book is [The Crucible of Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Crucible_of_Time), by John Brunner. Now I just need to go find a copy to lose myself in...

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like "The Bug Wars" by Robert Asprin. First published in 1979.
It involves a war between intelligent lizard like beings and an insectoid race.